# Prove that for all $b \in \Bbb{R}$ there exists a point $a \in A$ such that |a - b| = inf{ |x-a| : $x \in A$ }

Tags: real-analysis

I'm self-studying real analysis using A course in mathematical analysis by Garling

One of the problems after the subsection on closed sets reads

Suppose that A is a non-empty closed subset of $\Bbb{R}$
Prove that for all $b \in \Bbb{R}$ there exists a point $a \in A$ such that |a - b| = inf{ |x-a| : $x \in A$ }

I think that letting A = [0, 1] and b = 3 is a counter example to this as { |x-a| : $x \in A$ } contains no numbers > 1 for any a $\in$ A and |a - b| $\geq$ 2

Could someone explain why my counterexample isn't a valid counterexample or is the book wrong?

Comment: The problem statement is wrong. The assertion should be that $|a-b| = \inf\{|x-b| : x \in A\}$. In words, $A$ contains a point $a$ which is closest to $b$.

Comment: Note that if $a \in A$, then $\inf \{|x - a| : x \in A\}$ is zero, so the assertion in the problem statement is clearly false if $b \not\in A$.

Comment: @Bungo I figured that inf{|x−a|:x∈A} is zero. I think your first comment is right as that assertion is quite easy to prove with what is discussed in the subsection. The main reason I asked  was that none of the errata mention it.